# Git Bash doesn't work after I updated Git for 2.27 on Windows

Tags: git-bash, git-for-windows

Git asked me if I wanted to upgrade to 2.27. I did it.
Now when I try to do Git Bash on any folder, nothing happens.
I uninstalled and installed again and added it to ESET NOD as a safe program. Nothing happened

But Git GUI works as usual.

[image]

Comment: how did git told you to update? Where do you usually get your install from?

Comment: Can you check if your `%PATH%` environment variable contains the path to git binaries : `C:\Program Files\Git\ ` ?

Comment: I uninstalled 2.27 and reinstalled again 2.26... and worked